# How to automatically arrange shapes automatically drawn by loop?

Tags: vba, visio

I have a loop that generates rectangles automatically on a visio drawing but I need to have the script to arrange them automatically  right know I recorded a macro while I rearranged the rectangles manually under the title box. But my rectangle count change constantly because the results from my if statement change constantly because my data continuously changes. I need for my loop to start drawing them under the  title box in columns of six or seven rectangles.

```
For I = 1 To WS_Count

Set vsoShape = 
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop(Application.DefaultRectangleDataObject, 
aoffset, boffset)

vsoShape.Text = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name


aoffset = aoffset

boffset = boffset + 0.75

Dev_Count = Dev_Count + 1


ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = DiagramServices

   Next I
```

I need to be able to set a starting position to begin dropping the rectangles below the title rectangle creating a new column every six to seven rectangles. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment aOffset every time `I` is divisible by the number of shapes you want horizontally...

You can do this with the [Mod Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mod-operator) `If (iterator Mod runEveryXIterations = 0) Then ...`

The example below should clarify the idea, the code is not exactly what you need but you should be able to grasp the idea:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub printXY()
    xyDistribute 10, 3, 0, 0, 0.75, 1.5
End Sub

Private Function xyDistribute(ByRef iterations As Long, _
                              ByRef newColAfter As Long, _
                              ByRef xPosInitial As Double, _
                              ByRef yPosInitial As Double, _
                              ByRef xStep As Double, _
                              ByRef yStep As Double)
    Dim iter As Long
    Dim xPos As Double
    Dim yPos As Double

    yPos = yPosInitial
    xPos = xPosInitial

    Debug.Print "xPos", "yPos"

    For iter = 1 To iterations

        Debug.Print xPos, yPos
        ' your code goes here

        If (iter Mod newColAfter = 0) Then
            yPos = yPos + yStep
            xPos = xPosInitial
        Else
            xPos = xPos + xStep
        End If

    Next iter

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks the code is very informative. I was able to create with mod but moving the shapes to a new column every 6 shapes but every column started with the first shape again I could't figure out how to do the if statement so it excluded the worksheets that were already processed. Again Thanks I really appreciate your help.

Comment: if you use `I` or `iter` respectively and not xPos or yPos to get your Worksheets you should never get the same one. Check what the variabel you use to access the `Worksheet` in the `Worksheets` collection represents.